# Boxplot using absolute frequencies

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
|Regions | F1 | F2 | F3 | ... | Fn |
|Region_1| X11| X12| X13| ... | X1n|
|Region_2| X21| X22| X23| ... | X2n|
...
|Region_k| Xk1| Xk2| Xk3| ... | Xkn|
```

Where every row represents an Italian region and every column is a feature that the individuals living in that region have. The value $X_{ij}$ is the number of individuals living in the region *i* and having the feature *j*, so the sum of each row gives the popolation living in that region; the sum of each column gives the people having that feature.

Boxplot depicts groups of numerical data through their quartiles. It is correct to create a boxplot on the columns of my data? It gives the correct information or I have to apply some transformation on my data (e.g., scaling, normalization, etc)?

Comment: Every *Xij* is an absolute frequency.

Comment: Do you want to summarise each column or do you want to compare the distributions?

Comment: I want to summarise each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boxplot will aggregate your values by *columns* so if you want to know for each feature the distribution of people with that characteristic, you can do it and it **could** be useful, but it's still not clear to me what do you mean with "it make sense and it gives the correct informations".

Comment: these data are absolute frequencies, it is correct to use a boxplot on them?

Answer (score 2):

To Fracesco's answer I would add that if features are measured in different scales (example: height, weight, income, number of children...), each boxplot will make sense in its own but comparing them in the same graph and the same scale won't make sense - and that is what boxplot(myDataFrame) does.